# Add speed for every prefab

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hello guys i work on some reflex tapping game in unity  and i need script for every 2 or more prefab destroy to add speed on my player and i need that constatly adding speed for 2 prefbas. Can someone help me whit that i do like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Sphere"))
        {

        count = count + 1;

        if(count >= highScore)
        {
            highScore = count;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", highScore);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }

        SetCount();


        if(count == 2)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, 50 * forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making `Speed` a property of your `Player` class:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
}
```

You would need to make sure to multiply by this property when you move the player (I'm assuming your code is similar to this):

```
rigidbodyReference.AddForce(0, 0, 50 * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Then, I would make a static `GameManager` class that will keep track of the number of prefabs:

```
public static class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PrefabCount;
}
```

Finally, I would add a `speedIncrement` variable (exposed to the inspector) as a property of your `Player` class and modify your `OnTriggerEnter` method:

```
public float speedIncrement;

// ...

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // This will reduce unnecessary nesting in your code to make it easier to read
    if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag("Sphere"))
        return;

    // Same thing as GameManager.PrefabCount = GameManager.PrefabCount + 1
    GameManager.PrefabCount++; 

    if (GameManager.PrefabCount >= highScore)
    {
        highScore = GameManager.PrefabCount;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", highScore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    // Use the Modulus operator to determine if the PrefabCount is evenly divisible by 2
    if (GameManager.PrefabCount % 2 == 0)
        Speed += speedIncrement; // Increase speed by whatever value set in the inspector
}
```